# How to change color of each bar in bar plot and high of description above each bar in Python Pandas Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have DataFrame and bar plot in Pandas in Python like below:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({"Clients" : [10, 20, 30, 40]}, index = ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"])

ax = DF.plot.bar(figsize=(17,5), grid=True, color=["green", "red", "blue", "cyan"], edgecolor='white')
ax.set(ylim=(0, 50))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'\n{p.get_height()}',
                (p.get_x()+0.25,
                 p.get_height()),
                ha="center",
                color="red",
                size=15)
```

As a result of above code I have bar plot like below:

[image]

I need to change 2 things:

1. How can I change color of each bar in bar plot? I need to have each bar in different color.
2. How can I raise the description of the individual bar, because currently I desctiption of each bar in definitely to close to bar.

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To color the bars individually, you can directly use matplotlib's `bar`plot instead of the pandas function.

To easily label bars, the latest matplotlib has a new function [`bar_label()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Clients": [10, 20, 30, 40]},
                  index=["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 5))
bars = ax.bar(df.index, df['Clients'], color=["green", "red", "blue", "cyan"])
ax.set(ylim=(0, 50))
# ax.margins(y=0.1) # easier method to reserve some extra space
ax.bar_label(bars, size=15, color='red')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with individual colors]

PS: If, for some reason, you want to keep closer to your original code, you could set the bar color in the same loop that add the labels. In the original code, you can set the `\n` at the end (`f'{p.get_height()}\n'`) to obtain a better spacing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Clients": [10, 20, 30, 40]},
                  index=["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"])
ax = df.plot.bar(figsize=(17, 5), grid=True, edgecolor='white', legend=False)
ax.set(ylim=(0, 50))
for p, color in zip(ax.patches, ["green", "red", "blue", "cyan"]):
    p.set_facecolor(color)
    ax.annotate(f'{p.get_height()}\n',
                (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2,
                 p.get_height()),
                ha="center",
                va="center",
                color="red",
                size=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How to use get height ?

Comment: In your original code, you iterated through the bars and called `get_height()` on them.  If you're using `ax.bar_label(...)`, `get_height()` is called behind the scene. I updated the answer with some code closer to the original.